# How do I take the nth element of multiple arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I have an array of arrays, and I want to grab the nth element of each of those arrays (starting with the "startIndex" array) and then form an array out of that.  So I have

```
  row_data = []
  data_cols[startIndex..(data_cols.size)].each do |data_col|
    row_data.push(data_col[row]) 
  end
```

Although the above works, it seems like more code than I need.  Is there a shorter way to write this?

Comment: If your code works consider moving this to [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your variable names, this would be a shorter version of your code :

```
data_cols.drop(startIndex).map{ |data_col| data_col[row] }
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is

```
arr[start..finish].map { |a| a[n - 1] }
```

Example, let's say you had a multi-dimensional array like so

```
arr = [[4,6,5],[3,4,7],[9,1,2]];
```

And you wanted to find the middle element in each array, starting from the first index. You would do this

```
arr[1..2].map { |a| a[1] };
=> [4,1]
```

If you would like to store this in a new variable you would prefix the above line with `var =`

If you want to destructively modify the array, use `map!` instead

Comment: Hi, Thanks.  I'm having some trouble translating this into my example.  What is "n" in the "n-1" section?  I'm getting an undefined variable there.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
new_arr = Array.new
arr[startIndex..endIndex].each do |a|
  new_arr << a[n - 1]
end
```